# When are Content Scripts added to the tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there race condition between background.js and content scripts?

For an extension, background.js calculates heavily asynchronously and task completion may take a while. But if the extension loads content script into the tabs, while background.js did not finish up, this may create problems. Content script sends messages to be responded by background.js. If background.js did not add listeners for messages, "the receiving end does not exit" throw may be called.

I need to figure out when content scripts are loaded into the tabs in relation to background.js is added to the browser?

Is it possible to moderate addition of content script to the tabs by background page?

Comment: No relation if you mean the scripts declared in manifest.json. Extension pages and web page tabs run in separate processes (per URL origin). You can simply inject the content script programmatically. Or use messaging from the background page. Or you can use service workers in extension's background page (works in Chrome only).

Comment: Thanks. If I need to get info from background page by sending messages, but the background page is not ready, should I simply use a setTimeout to call the background page after a specific time?

Comment: setTimeout seems good enough. You may show a spinner icon in your webpage UI if you have one when no response is received after e.g. 100ms.